# How to calculate return in data.table?

Tags: r, data.table, finance, quantitative-finance

I am new on stack overflow and an R beginner.

I want to calculate the returns of a big data set which looks like this:

```
Date        C1  C2  C3
31.01.1985  NA  47  NA
28.02.1985  NA  45  NA
29.03.1985  130 56  NA
30.04.1985  140 67  NA
31.05.1985  150 48  93
28.06.1985  160 79  96
31.07.1985  160 56  94
30.08.1985  160 77  93
30.09.1985  160 66  93
31.10.1985  160 44  93
29.11.1985  160 55  93
```

It's a `data.table` format, let's say it's called Prices, columns are the companies, values are the prices, the real data set has many more columns and rows. I want to build a new DT where I calculate the monthly returns, I know you can do this with the `diff()` function. but how do I build my new Data table with so many columns without for loops?

I thought of:

```
Returns <- diff(Prices[, names(Prices) != "Date"])
```

but this for some reason only gives out:

```
[1] 1 0 0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting that output is because `Prices[, names(Prices) != "Date"]` returns a logical vector:

```
> Prices[, names(Prices) != "Date"]
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And because you can do calculations with logicals, you can also use `diff` on a logical vector. `FALSE` is then treated as a `0` and `TRUE` as a `1`. So basically you were doing `diff(c(0,1,1,1))`.

---

A possible solution for what you want:

```
cols <- setdiff(names(Prices),"Date")

# option 1:
Prices[, paste0(cols,"_return") := lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - shift(x, fill = NA))/shift(x, fill = NA)), .SDcols = cols][]

# option 2:
Prices[, paste0(cols,"_return") := lapply(.SD, function(x) c(NA,diff(x))/shift(x, fill = NA)), .SDcols = cols][]
```

which gives:

> ```
> > Prices
>           Date  C1 C2 C3  C1_return   C2_return   C3_return
>  1: 1985-01-31  NA 47 NA         NA          NA          NA
>  2: 1985-02-28  NA 45 NA         NA -0.04255319          NA
>  3: 1985-03-29 130 56 NA         NA  0.24444444          NA
>  4: 1985-04-30 140 67 NA 0.07692308  0.19642857          NA
>  5: 1985-05-31 150 48 93 0.07142857 -0.28358209          NA
>  6: 1985-06-28 160 79 96 0.06666667  0.64583333  0.03225806
>  7: 1985-07-31 160 56 94 0.00000000 -0.29113924 -0.02083333
>  8: 1985-08-30 160 77 93 0.00000000  0.37500000 -0.01063830
>  9: 1985-09-30 160 66 93 0.00000000 -0.14285714  0.00000000
> 10: 1985-10-31 160 44 93 0.00000000 -0.33333333  0.00000000
> 11: 1985-11-29 160 55 93 0.00000000  0.25000000  0.00000000
> ```

If you want to create a new `data.table`, you could use one of the following two options:

```
# option 1:
Returns <- Prices[, c(list(Date = Date), lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - shift(x, fill = NA))/shift(x, fill = NA))), .SDcols = cols]

# option 2:
Returns <- copy(Prices)
Returns[, (cols) := lapply(.SD, function(x) (x - shift(x, fill = NA))/shift(x, fill = NA)), .SDcols = cols]
```

---

Used data:

```
Prices <- fread("Date        C1  C2  C3
31.01.1985  NA  47  NA
28.02.1985  NA  45  NA
29.03.1985  130 56  NA
30.04.1985  140 67  NA
31.05.1985  150 48  93
28.06.1985  160 79  96
31.07.1985  160 56  94
30.08.1985  160 77  93
30.09.1985  160 66  93
31.10.1985  160 44  93
29.11.1985  160 55  93")[, Date := as.Date(Date, "%d.%m.%Y")]
```

Comment: Oh this works like a charm, thank you very much, you dont know how helpful you have been. I have a few questions to understand this better. a) why did you use the [] at the end of your first two options? secondly, when you created the data.table why did you use (cols) in option two? sorry if these are dumb questions, but I am really trying to understand R and especially data.table. thank you again

Comment: @AahuM To answer your questions: **(a)** I used `[]` to make `data.table` print the result to the console immediately; it is not necessary to use this; **(b)** I used `(cols)` in option two because then the columns are updated by reference. When you want to learn more about `data.table`, you could also study the [*Getting started*](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started) vignettes.

Comment: thanks for your answers, I understand it better now. yes, I will study the getting started vignettes.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a function to work on a single column of values

```
pc.change <- function(x) {   
(c(x[2:length(x)], NA) - x)*100/x }
```

And then apply this to a matrix of all the columns of values

```
d <- read.table(text = "Date        C1  C2  C3
31.01.1985  NA  47  NA
28.02.1985  NA  45  NA
29.03.1985  130 56  NA
30.04.1985  140 67  NA
31.05.1985  150 48  93
28.06.1985  160 79  96
31.07.1985  160 56  94
30.08.1985  160 77  93
30.09.1985  160 66  93
31.10.1985  160 44  93
29.11.1985  160 55  93", header = TRUE)

apply(as.matrix(d[,2:4]), 2, pc.change)
```

This gives me

```
            C1         C2        C3
[1,]       NA  -4.255319        NA
[2,]       NA  24.444444        NA
[3,] 7.692308  19.642857        NA
[4,] 7.142857 -28.358209        NA
[5,] 6.666667  64.583333  3.225806
[6,] 0.000000 -29.113924 -2.083333
[7,] 0.000000  37.500000 -1.063830
[8,] 0.000000 -14.285714  0.000000
[9,] 0.000000 -33.333333  0.000000
[10,] 0.000000  25.000000  0.000000
[11,]       NA         NA        NA
```

It should then be possible to convert this into a data table if needed